# How to use the method on middleware laravel

Tags: laravel

this my middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckSession
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

    public function CheckSessionPageReuestTokenFailed($request, $next)
    {
        if ($request->session()->has('request_failed')) {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            echo 'forbidden';
        }
    }

}
```

how i can use method CheckSessionPageReuestTokenFailed($request, $next)?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you have written this method ?. you can write this code into handle method.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->session()->has('request_failed')) {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            echo 'forbidden';
        }
    }
```

and also you need register this middleware into `$routeMiddleware` array in
`app/Http/Kernel.php`  file. 
add this line: 
 `'CheckSession' => CheckSession::class,`

read laravel documentation to know more  https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware

Comment: because I will make more than 1 function in the daloam middleware that?

Comment: you can write multiple functions in middleware but you must call those function in handle method. You must use registered middleware name in route

Answer (score 0):

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
     $this->CheckSessionPageReuestTokenFailed($request, $next);

     return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: can I put it directly on the route?

Comment: Yes.  Using the Class, 'CheckSession'. 
 Please read https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes

Answer (score 0):

You can use inside `handle()` method.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $this->CheckSessionPageReuestTokenFailed($request, $next);
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Suppose I have 1 method again, and I want to be more specific use the method 2, how do I call a method to 2 it?

example :
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $this->CheckSessionPageReuestTokenFailed($request, $next);
    $this->CheckSessionPageReuestTokenFailed2($request, $next);
    return $next($request);
}

how i can call method $this->CheckSessionPageReuestTokenFailed2($request, $next); on route or controller

Comment: The same way as in the example. You can also check whether the first method return true or false to call the method 2

Comment: In your routes file you should add the middleware. Like this: 
    
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'example', 'middleware' => 'checksession'], function () {

 });

and in your `Http/Kernel.php` you should add `'checksession' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckSession::class`